# Forcing php insertion to start on a new line in WordPress header file

Tags: php, wordpress, insertion

I have various plugins and homemade functions that add items to my wordpress blog header.php file. Today I was doing some tweaks and noticed this issue with where these code snipets get inserted.

I had the following code in my header:

[My code in my header](http://pastebin.com/wfTZ7aDW)

The Facbook debugger then told me that the og:type tag "article" was missing. It seems that the comment code was hiding the first meta property tag.

Those tags are from my homemade function in my function.php file so I want to know how can I force the insertion to start on a new line and not get tacked on the end of whatever line it wants.

I looked at /n but can't get it to work in my function

[Doug's Function](http://pastebin.com/7TNCiPE4)

Any help would be great

Comment: How is the comment code hiding it? The comment is closed and the meta tag is outside of it so it should not effect it.

Comment: I don't know why. The Facebook debugger tells me the particular meta tag that is directly next to the comment is missing I figured I would force a new line in my function to make sure that doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Figured my issue out. I wasn't getting how to get my function to force a new line and figured out that I needed to put in a PHP declaration so here is the line I added to my function:

```
<?php echo "\n<!-- my comment -->\n"; ?>
```

That worked. It dropped down to the next line, wrote the comment, then dropped another line before writing the rest of the text in the function.

Comment: This seems more of problem in FB debugger than your code, which is otherwise valid. The debugger is apparently not properly parsing the code. If you can I would open up a bug report on it.

Comment: Not a real big for me as it just made me deal with this issue to solve it. I just don't like code getting inserted willy nilly. I might let FB know